# Making Ubuntu Linux pretty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface

Mac and Windows Vista have such pretty user interfaces with all the transparencies and stuff. Is there anything for Ubuntu Linux to improve the way it looks?

Answer (score 4):

My personal favorite is [Mac4Lin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mac4lin/), makes the Linux GUI more mac-like. **However I clearly recognize that this is a matter of personal preference**, so please don't downvote just because you don't agree!!!

From their website:

> [image: Screen Shot]
>
> The goal of this
>   project is to bring the Mac OS X user
>   interface to POSIX Operating Systems
>   (GNU/LInux, FreeBSD, openSolaris
>   etc.). The project is built for
>   desktop environments based on GTK --
>   Anirudh Acharya, Developer - Mac4Lin

Comment: I don't get these distributions/add ons that make your desktop look like a different OS. If you want your desktop to look a particular OS, why not just use that OS instead of trying to customise your current OS?

Comment: Because Mac OS only runs on Apple hardware and if you don't happen to have a Mac, you're SOL. Or, maybe you like the look of OS X but the functionality of Ubuntu.

Comment: It could be also a matter of money...I have an IBM T20 laptop (soooooooo *%&$£!* old) and it was a present...if I was a little richer I'd buy a Mac (maybe)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to [enable visual effects](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/desktop-effects/C/)?

Comment: Good idea! I will give it a try.

Comment: While there, enable the "extra" effects as well - there's link on this same page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go all in (or out, I don't remember) on eye-candy, you might want to check out [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/).

[image]

[image]

Now, that's

> pretty user interfaces with all the transparencies and stuff [!]

[Here's a guide](http://linuxhub.net/2009/10/install-compiz-fusion-on-ubuntu-karmic-koala/) for Karmic.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://gnome-look.org for pretty themes and backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a great look and feel and fancy features with using the KDE desktop. Install it with

```
sudo aptitude install kubuntu-desktop
```

or use the package manager or synaptic for it.

Gnome as well as KDE have lots of 3D effects and more if you enable it.